# Deducting the value of one django field in a model class from another model class

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am looking for a way to subtract from a field named total in the first class, which i get by multiplying the price and the quantity. It works well and the result is evident in the database. I would like, after calculating the total, to deduct that field by referencing it in my second class. Basically, the sales input value - the referenced total object should return a profit/loss and store that in a field named profit in the second class. I have tried a few ways, it posts the sales value but not the calculated value in terms of profit/loss. Is there something I am overlooking or I am oversimplifying the code?

```
    from django.db import models

    import datetime
    from django.utils import timezone
    from numpy import array
    
    class CowData(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
        user = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
        feed = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        total = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    # here i calculate the total by multiplying the price and the total

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.total = array(self.total)
            self.total = self.price * self.quantity
            super(CowData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            
    class Sales(models.Model):
        # total = models.ForeignKey(CowData, to_field='total', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=False)
        sales = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        profit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        
        # What I have tried :
        # def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #     self.profit = self.sales - self.total
        #     super(CowData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # here is where things are vague

        def profit_made(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.profit = self.sales - CowData.objects.get(pk=5).total
            super(CowData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize I had minor errors in my code. I have managed to solve it.

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    sales = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    profit = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.profit = self.sales - CowData.objects.get(pk=1).total
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```